# @local_config_python issue in RBE

Tags: python, bazel

I've been having this error while setting up remote exec with python.
The `@local_config_python` platform rule says it doesn't find the `Python-ast.h` file. Please, has anyone encountered a problem like that. Here's out it looks. I apologize for my lack of clarity, I don't really understand the problem.

[image: Bazel grpc build]

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you're trying to do, or what OS you're using? Might it be as simple as downloading the `.h` file from the following link, and placing it in the directories you see in your error messages? https://www.exefiles.com/en/h/python-ast-h/

Comment: The file actually exist both on the remote host instance and my computer. But it says it doesn't

Comment: Difficult to provide help without further details. Is this easily reproducible on other machines? What specific command produced the error shown? Finally what is the main objective that you want to achieve with your code?